# using variables with REGEX in python

Tags: python, regex, variables

I'm trying to search for specific word using python

```
f = open("C:\\Users\\Suleiman JK\\Desktop\\keyword.txt")
keyword = f.readlines() -----> keyword[0] = "obj"
file = open ("C:\\Users\\Suleiman JK\\Desktop\\Hello.pdf")
text = file.readlines()


for line in text:
    if re.search (r"\b"+keyword[0]+r"\b"):
        print (line)
```

it doesn't give me the word I'm looking for

but when I use This it works fine:

```
for line in text:                                    
    if re.search (r"\b"+"obj"+r"\b"):
        print (line)
```

or when I use this it gives me "obj" and "endobj":

```
for line in text:                                    
    if re.search (keyword[0]):
        print (line)
```

could any one help me?

Comment: Are you sure `keyword[0]` is not `"obj\n"`? Try printing `repr(keyword[0])`.

Answer (score 1):

What happens is that the in reality, the string is:

```
"obj\n"
```

the character `"\n"` is called a new-line character, and it's used to separate lines.

**How to "delete" it?**

You can use the method [`rstrip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) from strings. This method will return a copy of the string with trailing characters removed. By default it will *remove all whitespaces*:

```
keyword[0].rstrip()
```

So, in your case, you can use it like:

```
re.search (r"\b" + keyword[0].rstrip() + r"\b")
```